# How to center checkbox vertically in a table-cell?

Tags: html, css

Q: How do I center the checkbox vertically? In this particular case, why is there empty space between checkbox borders and the containing element at all given that margin and padding are 0 for all elements?

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TZMF5/2/

HTML:

```
<div class="category-item">
    <span class="input-container">
        <input type="checkbox"/>
     </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.category-item {
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.category-item .input-container {
  display: table-cell;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.category-item .input-container input {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

There are similar questions on SO to this. Couldn't find an answer that would work for this case. Thx!

Comment: Add `float: left;` to `.category-item .input-container input`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The issue..

Checkbox elements, like other input elements are subject to vendor specific `appearance` styling- you can override this by using `appearance:none` or `-webkit-appearance:none` etc..however this will then stop the checkbox from rendering at all.

As such, you have to 'live' with the default styling to some extent and implement a few overrides, for vertical alignment in the example you have given, you have to 'bump it up' by 1px, eg:

```
.category-item .input-container input {
    margin:-1px 0 1px 0; /* <-- here */
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/TZMF5/4/)

[**More on `appearance` from MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance)

> The -moz-appearance [sic] CSS property is used in Gecko (Firefox) to
>   display an element using a platform-native styling based on the
>   operating system's theme.

---

### Styling your own checkbox

A workaround is to 'replace' the checkbox element entirely, whilst still retaining its functionality- this can be done by adding a `label` element then applying som nifty CSS, for example, the below:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/TZMF5/21/)

HTML

```
<div class="category-item">
    <div class="input-container">
        <input class='checkbox' id='checkbox' type="checkbox" />
        <label for='checkbox' class='checkbox'></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.category-item {
    display: table;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height:30px;
}
.category-item .input-container {
    display: table-cell;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height:30px;
}
label.checkbox {
    position:relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border:1px solid black;
    height:10px;
    width:10px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    margin:-2px 0 2px 0;
    line-height:1em;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:inline-block;
}
input.checkbox {
    appearance:none;
    height:0;
    width:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
}

input.checkbox:checked +label.checkbox:before {
    content:'\2713';
    position:absolute;
    top:-3px;
    font-size:10px;
    left:2px;
}
```

Comment: Thx, best answer so far. Is vertical-align necessary in .category-item .input-container there? Also, margins -1px 0 1px 0; fixes the problem on Chrome, but on Firefox it still doesn't align correctly. No way to avoid that I guess unless I use different css for different browsers?

Comment: @vrepsys - the only way would be to actually create your own checkbox style- e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/TZMF5/19/

Comment: Accepting this answer because the question was more 'why' rather than 'how to fix this'. But actually the problem was fixed by the answer below by @graphicdivine, perhaps I'll include this in the question itself.

Answer (score 3):

Adding `display: block;` to the input will close up the vertical spacing.  Otherwise, it's being treated as an inline item.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TZMF5/13/)

Answer (score 0):

use vertical-align: middle on input-container, not on the input tag itself

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TZMF5/3/

```
.category-item .input-container {
    display: table-cell;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.category-item .input-container input {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Not working for me. Doesn't vertical-align have to be on elements _inside_ the table cell rather than table cell itself?

Comment: tested it in chrome, ff and safari, check the link to jsfiddle i added to my answer

Comment: No it doesn't work, you just made the slight misalignment invisible by increasing the category-item height. If you remove height: 50px it's still misaligned.

Comment: what i was trying to do, is to align the checkbox vertically in the middle, depending on the height (eg. 50px or whatever) of the containing div, by setting the vertical-align property right . the solution with display: block, that did the trick for you, doesn't align the checkbox in the middle, it fixes your margin, padding problem

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the next result is what you want. I only have commented two rules.

```
.category-item .input-container input {
    /*margin: 0;*/
    padding: 0;
    /*vertical-align: middle;*/
}
```

The result is a centered box.