# Vertical align checkbox to the center of button in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to align checkbox vertically center to the button, but it is not working

**What I have now:**

[image]

**Expected:** (about 5 px down)

[image]

**What I tried:**

Tried to add top padding/margin for the checkbox but did not work.

**Here is the code...**

https://jsfiddle.net/z4b2bwg6/13/

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr class="info">
            <th class="col-md-2"><input type="checkbox" class="app-all"/>&nbsp<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Modify</button></th>                               
            <th class="col-md-1 text-center">Comments</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="Container" data-filteredresult=""></tbody>
</table>
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this to your code  here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z4b2bwg6/16/)

```
input, button{vertical-align:middle;}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `vertical-align:middle` and remove the `margin-top` being set.

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    margin-top: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tbzwv3f6/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use negative margin on the checkbox like this:

```
input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio] {
    margin:-2px 0 0px 0; /* <-- here */
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle with above codes: https://jsfiddle.net/z4b2bwg6/15/

> Source: [How to center checkbox vertically in a table-cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23805018/how-to-center-checkbox-vertically-in-a-table-cell)

Answer (score 1):

Try below code,

```
.checkboxContainer{display:table}
.checkboxContainer input[type="checkbox"]{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z4b2bwg6/17/